# Configuring pop-up in map notes of ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, map-notes

Whenever I try to create my own layer in ArcGIS using Add->Add Map Notes, there is no Configure Pop-up option in newly created layer

[image: No "Configure Pop-up option"]

Whereas if I use already existing one there is such an option

[image]

Is there any way to have a Cofigure Pop-up option, or any other way to add attributes to the new layer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Map Viewer Classic, it appears you construct your pop-up to the [Map Notes](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_D535374C2B014362976F39BCD4B8DB95) layer when you first add it to the map. For example:

[image]

[image]

You might be interested in the enhanced popups of the [new Map Viewer](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/note-this-sketching-now-available-in-map-viewer/).